# Does my MacOS internal drive partitioning scheme look correct after recovery?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partitioning

I recently had to recover Monterey on my Macbook Pro because I lost my Macintosh HD for some odd reason. Anyway after reinstalling Monterey in recovery mode, my partition scheme looks like this:

[image]

Everything seems to work, but in Terminal, navigating through `/Volumes` I recurse through `Macintosh HD` hard links, which seems odd.

[image]

My question is should I back up `Macintosh HD - Data` and re-partition the SSD into a more sane scheme? Is there a picture of a default partition scheme for Monterey?

Comment: `/Volumes/Macintosh HD` is a symbolic link, not a hard link. macOS creates it for the root volume automatically, so you can consistently access your volumes under `/Volumes/<volume name`. And the recursion behavior is also normal.